# Fail to send image ( byte[] ) as parameter of WCF service

Tags: wcf

I wrote some service that have method that get image ( byte[] ) as parameter ( return void ).

I also wrote some client (client & server run on same machien - different sulotion - using IIS )that send the bitmap ( as byte[] ) to the service - and each time i try to send i get the exception:

**An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost/WebService/Service.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down)**

I added one more method that get void and return int - and i can call this method with no problem.

What can be wrong ? Do i need to define something speciel in the client service reference ?

The service method

```
[ServiceContract]
**public interface IService**
{
    [OperationContract]
    void GetPic( byte[] pic );
}

**public class Service : IService**
{
    public void GetPic( byte[] pic )
    {
          ...   
    }
 }
```

Web.config file:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="ServiceProxy.Service">

    <endpoint 
      name="basicHttp"
      address="" 
      binding="basicHttpBinding" 
      bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="Contracts.IService">
    </endpoint>

    <endpoint 
      address="mex" 
      binding="mexHttpBinding" 
      contract="IMetadataExchange" >
    </endpoint>

    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/ServiceProxy/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>

  </service>
</services>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>       
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Can you show/share the actual method?

Comment: The client method or the service method ?

Comment: I guess the service method for a start.

Comment: I check also that the image is not very big -

Comment: Add code of the section 'services' in your web.config. There is an obvious problem in endpoint configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must configure your binding on server to accept large messages. By default it accepts only messages up to 65KB and arrays with 16k elements = in your case bitmap which has size less then 16KB.

Use this in your web.config (server side):

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="myBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="1000000" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

In your endpoint configuration reference this binding in `bindingConfiguration` attribute by setting it to `myBinding`.